# JavaScript script to validate minimum words entered in input

Tags: javascript, input, contacts, minimum

I really don't know how to do this. So I need a JavaScript script that'd look at the contact form field (question name) and make sure it has more than one word before submitting it.

```
<input type="text" name="question[name]" id="question_name">
```

I really searched a lot, found some solutions but non of them really worked.

Can you help me?

Comment: Are you using JavaScript to submit the form? Can you show us more of your code?

Comment: This doesn't look like a valid question. Please show what you have tried so far (in terms of source code), what results you got and how are those results different than the expected ones. Otherwise it's pretty hard to have any constructive conversation on StackOverflow. It looks more like a rent-a-coder or something question which is not the purpose of this site.

Comment: what is one word? does `i` qualify?

Comment: This is the REGEX to test for at least 2 words: `@"^[a-zA-Z]{2,40}\s*[a-zA-Z]{2,40}*$"` (assumes that 1 character is not a word)

Comment: The general idea involves parsing the string, splitting on whitespace (and creating a string array from it) and then counting the number of elements in the array.  Have you tried something like that?

Comment: I tried these codes:

`<input type="text" name="question[name]" id="question_name" onkeypress="activateSubmit();">

<input id="question_submit" name="commit" type="submit" value="Contact Support" disabled="disabled">

<script>
  function activateSubmit(){
    var len = $('#question_name').val().split(" ").length;
    if(len >= 1){
      $('#question_submit').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
    else{
      $('#question_submit').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
  }
</script>`

Comment: `<script>
$('form#count').submit(function(){
    // if we accept that words are only made of letters
    if ($(this).find('textarea').val().match(/[a-z]+/gi).length < 15) {
        // add some error message
        return false; // prevents submitting
    }
});
</script>`

Comment: one word shoud be 3 or more characters, so "abc abc" should pass, "abc" and "ab ab" shouldn't, "one word" should....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<input type="text" name="question[name]" id="question_name" onblur="this.value.split(' ').length < 2 ? alert('you need more words here') : '';" />
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2pW6q/)

---

**Edit** to improve it:

HTML code:

```
<p>
    <input type="text" name="question[name]" id="question_name" onblur="CheckErrors.Name(this);" />
    <span class="error"></span>
</p>
```

JS code:

```
var CheckErrors = {

    Config: {
        Error_Strings: {
            Name: 'you need more words here',
            Email: 'the email looks invalid'
            //, ....
        }
    },

    Name: function(element){
        try{
            var error_target = element.nextElementSibling;
            if( element.value.split(' ').length < 2 ){
                error_target.textContent = this.Config.Error_Strings.Name;
            }
            else{
                error_target.textContent = '';
            }
        }
        catch(e){
            console.log(e.stack);
        }
    }

    //, Email: function(element){}....
};
```

Comment: I guess this is the solution. 

Can I ask you how could I implement nicer method, but "nicer" I mean not using alert. E.g. to text be showen on right side of input form?

Comment: Of course, I edited my post to show you an easy object oriented solution. [check jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kmsdev/2pW6q/1/)

Answer (score 2):

Here a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/6q8jJ/4/

html

```
<input type="text" name="question[name]" id="question_name">
<button onclick="validate();">send</button>
```

js

```
function validate(){

    var error = 0,
    el = document.getElementById("question_name");

    if(el.value.replace(/\s+/g, '').length <= 1){ //get value, remove all whitespace, get length
        error++;
    }

    /*
    * etc
    * your other validation
    */


   if(error > 0) {
       alert('mhh...');
   }else{
       alert('ok send for real');
   }

}
```

Comment: Hmm this script is checking for letters not words. So if you type "a" it's not passing but if you enter "aa" it's passing. Any solution for checking words?

Comment: aa in js is a word (maybe in english is meaningless but in maybe in some language it exists). If you have to check real words (existing words with meaning) you need to validate that with database or a service. If you have only a few words, you can store them into an array, so the script need changes.